# Java Inheritance, Constructor and "super"

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

Hello everyone I recently started learning OOP in Java and I just have a few questions, I'll use my (probably poorly written) code to demonstrate.

Let me introduce my superclass first, Vehicle:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private String description;
    private double speed;
    private double tankLevel;

    public Vehicle(String description, double speed, double tankLevel) {
        this.description = description;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.tankLevel = tankLevel;
    }

    public Vehicle() {

    }

    public Vehicle(String description, double speed) {
        this.description = description;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void drive() {
        if(getTankLevel() != 0) {
            if(getSpeed() != 0) {
                System.out.println("Your " + getDescription() + " is driving");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You have enough fuel but your "+ getDescription() +" isn't running");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Tanklevel too low!");
        }
    }

    public double getTankLevel() {
        return tankLevel;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Now here is the subclass, VehicleMain, where my first question comes up:

```
public class VehicleMain extends Vehicle {

    public VehicleMain(String description, double speed, double tankLevel) {
        super(description, speed, tankLevel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Vehicle car = new Vehicle("car", 20, 5);
        
        car.drive();

    }
}
```

1. question: Is there a good way to explain why I need that constructor in VehicleMain?
2. question: Why do I use super() in the constructor?
3. question: In method drive() in my superclass, should I use the private String description, or the method getDescription() ?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How else will you create an Instance of VehicleMain if you dont have a constructor in the class?   You can do new Vehicle() but java will not know anything about VehicleMain in this case.


You dont have to do super if you dont want to.   You are calling super(params) ONLY if you want to initialize the parameters you inherited from your parent.  Otherwise, you can have your own VehicleMain properties, and your Parent could have its own properties but if you dont call super(properties), then those will be null

Answer (score 3):

1. `VehicleMain` extends class `Vehicle`. So you need to provide the required parameters to construct a `Vehicle` to the super class.
2. This relates closely to answer 1.  The `super()` call is required so that you can call the original constructor from `Vehicle` with the necessary parameters.

TBH `VehicleMain` seems completely unnecessary.  There's no reason for it to extend `Vehicle` as it doesn't add anything on top of `Vehicle`.  You could remove the extends and the call to the `VehicleMain` constructor and the program would run the same.

Comment: I just realized that too.. I misunderstood the assignment, I thought it was about practicing inheritance, turns out it wasn't..

Comment: Understanding the requirements is important! :-)